# How to make an intermediate printf()?

Tags: c, printf

Suppose I have a function name `my_print(int flag_1, /* what goes here? */)`.
Its objective is the same as printf(), but it should only print when flag_1 is "true".
How would I write the function's header and body?

Note: I know I can just write `if (flag_1) printf(/*something*/);`, but how would I put that into a function?

Comment: Thanks that was what I was looking for. But had some trouble with phrasing it.

Comment: No worries; it can be hard to search for an answer without knowing it :)